# Jest: How to access reporter instance from setupFilesAfterEnv script?

Tags: jestjs

I have my custom reporters

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  reporters: [‘default’, ‘customReporter.js’]
  ...
}
```

And I have a setup script which I hook to *setupFilesAfterEnv*

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [‘setup.js’]
  ...
}
```

How can I access *customReporter* instance from *setup.js*?

Comment: In no way. Consider explaining your case, this could be XY problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed what allure-jest did in https://github.com/zaqqaz/jest-allure/blob/master/src/setup.ts.

I changed my setup.js code in a way that my reporter implements Jasmine Reporter interface instead of Jest Reporter, then register as reporter using `jasmine.getEnv().addReporter()`.